# Is it possible to catch browser's File Open/Save dialog event using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, dom-events

Using Javascript is it possible to listen for browser's file open/save dialog box event. I want to perform an action when I am notified that the save file dialog box has opened now. Specifically I want to hide a loading spinner when dialog box opens (but this could very well be any other action )

I believe I can do that for a dialog box that I create, not sure if it can be done for the browser's standard dialog box.

Any pointers for that would be really helpful.

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser.aspx I think this might work for me

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3872406

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there is no event for that.

Comment: Why a let down? I would say it's a very good thing which protects users privacy. +1 by the way.

Comment: @BryanDowning, [The `beforeunload` event will fire when that dialog opens](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13698030/331508).

Comment: @BrockAdams, that does hit one useful scenario.  But it only works if they navigate to a zip, not if they hit Ctrl-O, Ctrl-S, right-click save image as, etc.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen, The question appears to be for the scenario when the page/app is preparing an individual file to download. Ctrl-O and Ctrl-S do not apply. Right-click would not apply either in the most common applications.

Answer (score 18):

Yes!  You can take advantage that most browsers (Tested okay on Chrome, Firefox, and IE) fire the `beforeunload` event just before the Individual-file Download dialog opens.

So code like this will work:

```
$(window).bind ("beforeunload",  function (zEvent) {
    // PERFORM DESIRED ACTIONS HERE.
    /* This code will fire just before the Individual-file Download 
       dialog opens.
       Note that it will also fire before the tab or window is closed, 
       but that should not be a problem for this application.
    */
} );
```

Open and run this snippet to see it in action:

```js
$(window).bind ("beforeunload",  function (zEvent) {
    $("#dwnldStatus").text ("This code runs just before the file open/save dialog pops up.");
} );

$("#directDwnload").click ( function () {
    fireDownload ();
} );

$("#ResetTimer").click ( function () {
    $("#dwnldStatus").html (
        'Download will start in <span id="timeleft">3</span> seconds.'
    );
    fireTimer (3);
} );

function fireDownload () {
    window.location.assign (
        "//phs.googlecode.com/files/Download%20File%20Test.zip"
    );
}

function fireTimer (secondsLeft) {
    this.secondsLeft    = secondsLeft || 30;
    this.countdownTimer = this.countdownTimer || null;

    if ( ! this.countdownTimer) {
        this.countdownTimer = setInterval ( function() {
                this.secondsLeft--;
                $("#timeleft").text (this.secondsLeft);
                if (this.secondsLeft <= 0) {
                    clearInterval (this.countdownTimer);
                    this.countdownTimer = null;
                    fireDownload ();
                }
            },
            1000
        );
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Activate one of the download buttons.  The timer button is just like any other javascript initiated download, no additional  click is needed.</p>
<p>The javascript detects when the File/Save dialog pops up and changes the status to "This code runs just before the file open/save dialog pops up.".</p>
<p>Note that it is not necessary to download the file. You can cancel the download.</p>

<div id="dwnldStatus"></div>
<button id="ResetTimer">Set timer to 3 seconds.</button>
<button id="directDwnload">Download the file now.</button>
```

---

Note that `beforeunload` will also fire before the tab or window is closed, so plan accordingly. That should not be an issue for this question as stated.

Comment: This works as needed. Not sure why this answer is not rated high.

Comment: Not very surprising after 10 years, but the `test.zip` link is down.

Answer (score -1):

Watch all elements that can invoke the file dialog.

For example, handle click events on `<input type="file" />` elements.
something like:

```
$('input:file').click(function(){ // onclick of file input
    $('.spinner').hide(); // hide spinner
});
```

Comment: I think he's talking about the regular File->Save, File->Open dialog boxes, and you can't watch e.g. the browser's toolbar or menubar.

Comment: I am talking about the dialog box you get when you download a file with content disposition as attachment. I think you can't watch that event. Thanks