# HTML new tab auto close

Tags: javascript, html

I not sure is this possible , but what I want is auto close for the new tab. Add `target="_blank"` in link it will redirect the url to the new tab, but how to close it automatically ? or maybe it show some text **eg: File Deleted**

Comment: What is the purpose of the new tab? are you opening it after a delete action and if so, is there any processing on the tab page happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open and then close a window without getting blocked as a popup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702344/how-to-open-and-then-close-a-window-without-getting-blocked-as-a-popup)

Comment: Probably you find this type of solution.. [See This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695537/opening-and-closing-a-new-tab-when-downloading)