# Is there a way to detect if a specific app is installed on (Android\iOS) device from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, deep-linking

I want to run JS code on Safari (iOS) or Chrome (Android) to detect for example, if *WhatsApp* is installed on the device.

I played with:

[How to check if an app is installed from a web-page on an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044805/how-to-check-if-an-app-is-installed-from-a-web-page-on-an-iphone)

and

https://github.com/hampusohlsson/browser-deeplink

But the problem is that if the app is installed on the device - the browser re-directs to the app. I want to stay on the page after the "detection stage", is that possible to do?

Comment: Just sharing an idea: if you try to open your app link with a window.open and then close it. Something like the flow at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695537/opening-and-closing-a-new-tab-when-downloading
But I don't know if can work in this particularly case.

Comment: Simple answer, no. No universal specification on app detection for browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following a few hours of research + consulting with top experts I came to the conclusion that **there is no legitimate way** of achieving the goal of detecting whether a specific app is installed on the device without having the browser re-direct to the app if it is installed.

In iOS for example, there was an app just removed from the App Store because of violating the rules: SysSecInfo. The app managed to pull list of all running processes for example.

From: https://www.sektioneins.de/en/blog/16-05-09-system-and-security-info.html

> See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/703/ "App
>   Detection" starting at 08:34
>
> During this talk they discuss several APIs used to gather information
>   about processes currently running on your system (around 12:12 in the
>   video) and claimed to have fixed them. However as so often Apple has
>   only partially fixed the problems they claim to have fixed. Therefore
>   they have actually never stopped malicious applications from gathering
>   information about what other applications run currently on your
>   device, but only removed access to detail information that is only
>   relevant for harmless system information tools anyway.
>
> System and Security Info is therefore still able to show the list of
>   running processes and enriches this list with information from the
>   codesigning information including the list of entitlements running
>   processes have.