# HTML/JQuery: How to close browser tab automatically after word document download (ms-word:ofe|u|)?

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint, ms-word, anchor

In HTML, If i use following link in anchor tag:

```
a href = "http://gugla.com/maadu.docx" target="_blank"
```

It opens document by opening new tab, downloading and close new tab itself.

As we need to use document for editing on download so Sharepoint team has given following URL:

```
a href = "ms-word:ofe|u|http://gugla.com/maadu.docx" target="_blank"
```

This opens document in editing mode on all browsers in word; but but but when document is saved after editing in word;; we see that "Browser Tab remained open and we need to close it manually".
[image]

**Note**: This link is present in iframe so i could not remove target blank as it will show "leave page stay on page" dialog which is also not required.

**UPDATE**: 
Created fiddle for my use case
http://jsfiddle.net/qxhzdmu6/
The link is not actual document but situation is same when word opens 
[image]

then it forgets there is tab at background

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695537/opening-and-closing-a-new-tab-when-downloading). I have not tested it but it might help you

Comment: @DanielAttard: Thanks, The situation is generated on fiddle you can refer here http://jsfiddle.net/qxhzdmu6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the link target to a hidden iframe that you leave on the page. Can't test on my OS, so let me know if this works for you.

```
<a href="ms-word:ofe|u|http://gugla.com/maadu.docx" target="myframe">Download</a>

<iframe style="background: transparent;" id="myframe" name="myframe" src=""></iframe>
```

Comment: thanks, it is working. But I use style="display: none;"

Comment: Awesome! I wasn't sure if there would be some sort of iframe "security" in Windows that would prevent operation if `display:none`

Comment: @MaksymPecheniuk: Thanks for confirming ;-) Accepting it as an answer.