# How to catch browser dialogs (e.g. "download or open") with Playwright for Python?

Tags: python, dialog, webautomation, playwright, playwright-python

I was trying to handle a browser dialog with Playwright for Python in Firefox (in this case, but I guess the browser does not matter), i.e. a dialog that was opened by Firefox to ask whether to open or save a file. The dialog pops up after I click a button. The link to the file is not exposed, so I cannot download it in another way.

I tried catching a `dialog` event:

```
with page.expect_event("dialog") as page_info:
    button = page.querySelector('button[id=\"download\"]')
    button.click()
```

which times out. I then thought I found the solution in [this GitHub ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python/issues/396). However, the following did not work either:

```
page.on("dialog", lambda dialog: dialog.accept())
page.click("button")
```

Do these kinds of dialog - in contrast to dialogs e.g. raised by JavaScript `alert()` - not trigger a `dialog` event? I think they may not, judging by the answers to this post: [Is it possible to catch browser's File Open/Save dialog event using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197955/is-it-possible-to-catch-browsers-file-open-save-dialog-event-using-javascript..).

If so, how can I accept or dismiss such a dialog using python-playwright?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems that this is simply not directly possible with `python-playwright`, nor is it going to be. From [this discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python/issues/460), I gathered that the dialog...

> "[...] is not a part of the web, it is a part of the browser, so we don't automate it."

There are workarounds, e.g. to trigger a download in a different way, but this would then not involve handling the browser dialog, as stated in the question.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```py
page.once("dialog", lambda dialog: dialog.accept())
```